# insert base64 string into mysql mediumblob

Tags: php, mysql, base64

After adding base64 string database, adds string twice instead of one time.
please help!!!

image to base64 string conversion and insert query for database.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrujg.png)
screenshot of database entry after query execution.

Comment: Please post code directly in the question, we cant copy screenshots.

Comment: move your insert query inside if condition

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It gets executed twice, since you execute it twice. 
You do two separate inserts. One before the if, one inside the if.

Just replace

```
$row = $conn->query('your sql');
if ($conn->query('your sql')) {
    /* ... */
}
```

with

```
$row = $conn->query('your sql');
if ($row) {
    /* ... */
}
```

**OR**

```
if ($conn->query('your sql')) {
    /* ... */
}
```